# Почему div не выводится?

Tags: html, css

Вот [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/aNFgq/):

Впервые сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой

**UPDATE**

Не выводится вот этот DIV:

```
#profile_menu {
height:160px;
width:240px;

background-color: #0F0;

position:relative;
top:100px;
left:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!-- Profile Menu -->
```

это html комментарий, в css нужно так:

```
/* Profile Menu */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aNFgq/1/

```js
var width = document.width;

$('#top_line').css({
  'width': 'width'
});

$('#top_panel').css({
  'width': width
});

$('#open_btn').css({
  'right': width / 12
});

$('#profile_pic').css({
  'right': width / 9.8
});

$('#notifications').css({
  'right': width / 7.8
});

$('#border').css({
  'right': width / 6.5
});

$('#settings').css({
  'right': width / 6
});

$('#search').css({
  'right': width / 5.4
});
```

```css
#top_line {
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #e1695b;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#top_panel {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #fcfcfb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#open_btn {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#down {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: relative;
  top: 6.5px;
  right: -5.7px;
}
#profile_pic {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#notifications {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #dd5c4e;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#notification_text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  top: -16px;
  left: 8px;
}
#border {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}
#settings {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #fcfcfb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#settings_ico {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3.1px;
  left: 3.5px;
}
#search {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #fcfcfb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#search_ico {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3.1px;
  left: 3.5px;
}
#profile_menu {
  height: 160px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: #0F0;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top_line"></div>
<div id="top_panel">
  <div id="open_btn">
    <img id="down" src="img/down.gif" />
  </div>

  <div id="profile_pic">
    <img id="profile_pic" src="img/profile_pic.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div id="notifications">-->
    <p id="notification_text">7</p>
  </div>

  <img id="border" src="img/border.gif" />

  <div id="settings">
    <img id="settings_ico" src="img/settings.gif" />
  </div>

  <div id="search">
    <img id="search_ico" src="img/search.gif" />
  </div>
</div>

<div id="profile_menu"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо Вам!

Comment: это все ночная невнимательность =)